# Input to the python join method can't be a list of numbers?

Tags: join

This gives me an error:

```
   a = [1,2,3]
   '\t'.join(a)
```

Is this because of the list elements being integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. Python needs explicit type conversion since it's strongly-typed.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> '\t'.join(map(str, a))
'1\t2\t3'
```

Function [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) applies `function` (passed as first argument) to `iterable` (passed as second argument).

In this case it converts ([str](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str)) each element of `a` into a string and returns the resulting list, that is consequently passed to method `join` of object `'\t'`.

Comment: Yeah, that explains it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Return a string which is the concatenation of **the strings in the iterable iterable.** The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

So the target should be array of strings.